# setting min depth in openni_kinect

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you setup minimum still acceptable depth in openni_kinect.
The problem is when trying to simulate Turtlebot and building maps with SLAM. Min depth is set too low and simulated laser picks up turtlebot itself resulting in poorly build maps.

Or can I adjust minimum depth somewhere else?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45301/setting-min-depth-in-openni_kinect/) by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2012-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found the solution. Needed to change parameters in turtlebot_description in gazebo.urdf.xacro under <xacro:macro name="turtlebot_sim_laser">

```
<minRange>0.30</minRange>
```

I also modified the angle of simulated laser, because it was way to big:

```
<minAngle>-57</minAngle>
<maxAngle>57</maxAngle>
```

---

Originally posted by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) with karma: 460 on 2012-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0